# ajaxform jQuery plugin reset form after sending request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chat

Before i begin I believe this is not a dublicate at first.

Here's my problem:

I have a chatroom php script that i use ajaxForm jQuery plugin in order to send new messages without reloading the whole page.

The fact is that posting takes about 1-2 secs with times:
e.g

Blocking:6ms

Sending:1ms

Waiting:1.15 sec

Recieving 1ms

```
$('#myform').ajaxForm(function() {
    //clear form after this
    $('#myform').clearForm();
});
```

The form is cleared after te recieving time,meaning it takes about 1.20sec to clear each message i send... and it seems like the chat lags for a bit.

I am trying to figure out a way to clear the form after the Sending part,without callback or something.

Comment: Is `#mydiv` a div that contains a form?

Comment: actually is the name of the form sorry, my mistake

Comment: OK, so the form has an ID of `#mydiv`?

Comment: yes (changed to myform)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ajaxForm` is working fine, you can do:

```
$('#myform').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit:  function() {
       $('#myform').clearForm();    //Call the reset before the ajax call starts
    },
    success: function(data){
       //Your normal callback here
    }
});
```

(If `$('#myform').clearForm()` didn't work use `$('#myform')[0].reset();`)

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Glad it helped you. Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mydiv').ajaxForm(function() {
   //...
    $("#mydiv")[0].reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `ajaxForm`, but just using the browser's [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset) function on the `<form>` element should suffice (I'm assuming that `ajaxForm` returns a jQuery instance):

```
$('#myform').ajaxForm(function() {
    this.reset();
});
```

If the above throws a `has no method reset()` error, try this:

```
$('#myform').ajaxForm(function() {
    $('#myform')[0].reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with `ajaxForm`. You could avoid `ajaxForm` with the following:

```
$(".ajaxform").submit(function(event){
   var $form = $(this);
   event.preventDefault();
   $form.get(0).reset();   //Call the js reset method before ajax starts
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
           //your code when response arrived here
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers